# SMTP shows success, but email never is delivered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, smtp, mailkit

My code work correctly with gmail domains but if I send any mail to anothet domain it show for me that the proccess seccessed but the mail don't receive any thing even junk mail.

```
public void send()
{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();

    MailboxAddress from = new MailboxAddress("Admin", "ahmed@gmail.com");
    message.From.Add(from);

    MailboxAddress to = new MailboxAddress("User","mohammed@gmail.com");
    MailboxAddress too = new MailboxAddress("User23","sara@ev-sa.com");
    message.To.Add(to);
    message.To.Add(too);

    message.Subject = "This is email subject";

    message.Body=new TextPart("plain"){
        Text="Hello"
    };

    using(var cli=new SmtpClient())
    {
        cli.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
        cli.Authenticate("ahmed@gmail.com", "password");
        cli.Send(message);
        cli.Disconnect(true);
    }
```

Comment: How many different domains have you tested with? If you email directly from gmail client from that from address to that to address does it arrive in the inbox?

Comment: mjwills .. yes it arrive in box for any mail uses gmail domain, but with vatient domainz which websites uses it doesn't sent any thing but it show that process success and from sender mail it show that the mail sent correctly

Comment: If you email directly from gmail client from that from address to that to address does it arrive in the inbox?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the email message is being delivered, it's just being filtered as spam at the destination mailbox.